# ZF2 - How to inject a service to a view?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a service class `MyService` that I use on the controllers by passing it as a parameter in the controller constructor. Needless to say, I use a factory to instantiate the controllers, and use the factory's service locator to retrieve `MyService` and then pass it to the instantiated controller.

```
// factory
$sl = $sl->getServiceLocator();
$ms = $sl->get(MyService::class);

return new MyController($sm);
```

Now, I need that service in the view. I tried creating a view helper that would take `MyService` as a dependency, (similar to the controller) like this:

```
// view helper factory
$ms = $sl->get(MyService::class);

return new MyServiceViewHelper($ms);
```

**However, it won't correctly instantiate `MyService`. It crashes saying:**

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to MyService::__construct() must be an instance of MyRepository, none given, called in /my-path/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php
```

`MyService` takes about 3 repositories as dependencies, that are provided naturally by the `MyServiceFactory`.  However, for some reason, the view helper isn't properly calling the factory or something like that, resulting in an incorrect instantiation.

So my next thought is: maybe this is not how you inject services to the view. So now I ask:

**How do I inject services to the views themselves?**

**Edit:** please don't say "pass it from the controller".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The viewhelpers are retrieved from a seperate pluginmanager `HelperPluginManager`, the same applies for the controllers which are managed by the `ControllerManager`.
To retrieve services from the "root" serviceManager you have to call `getServiceLocator()` in your factory as you did in the controller factory.

So your code should be:

```
// view helper factory
$sl = $sl->getServiceLocator(); //This line will do the trick
$ms = $sl->get(MyService::class);

return new MyServiceViewHelper($ms);
```